# VS Code Intellisense - unrelated methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I moved from old Windows laptop to a new one. I installed VS Code and transferred files and folders from .vscode in my user's directory to continue using the same settings and plugins.
Now in the VS code IntelliSense puts lots of unrelated methods on top of its list .add, .append, .capitalize, etc.

Example

[image: Example]

This happens with all objects I'm working with, whether it's a built-in or a user defined class.
My old laptop doesn't have this problem.
My language server is Pylance, I have IntelliSense enabled.
How can I fix that?

Comment: VS Code is an Interactive Development Environment (IDE). Honestly I suggest you start using these suggestions, because these are all methods which belong to the `list`-Object. If you do not want suggestions or interactive documentation about methods use a normal Code Editor like e.g. Sublime Text or Atom :) In the preferences you can likely turn suggestions off. But I wouldnt advise it

Comment: @5th he doesn't have problem with IntelliSense! The problem is that these methods are suggested as user snippet format.

Comment: my bad. Sorry I completely misunderstood the question. I should have known that `list` doesn't have an `add`-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have enabled `python snippets` extension. You can disable or uninstall it, or you can add this in the settings.json file:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
```

Comment: Would this affect user snippets?

Comment: @Shayan Yes, you can disable it.

Comment: But maybe he doesn't want to disable user snippets. Do you know what are **user** snippets?

Comment: @Shayan So I suggest him to disable this extension.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I deleted VS Code and installed it again and then manually enabled all the plugins and it started working. I checked editor.snippetSuggestions and it's set to inline on both laptops.

Comment: @Dmitry Ashmarin The `python snippets` extension caused this, you can try to disable it, it's not suggested to set `editor.snippetSuggestions`.

Comment: Thanks Steven. That was probably it. I indeed have python snippets extension, I checked it on my old laptop and it was disabled there. Maybe it was somehow enabled after I moved vs code profile. I can't verify it on my new laptop since I deleted the VS Code and installed it again.